# How do I set category values explicitly with dimple.js charts?

Tags: dimple.js

I want to draw a chart that always shows M, T, W, Th, F, Sa, Su on the x axis.

I start with:

```
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
x.addOrderRule(["M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa", "Su"]);
```

but that won't force those values to exist;  if my data only has "W" and "F", I'll only get two items on the x axis.

However, I want all 7 even if the data has no examples of some values.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I also posted this as an issue, but it's probably more appropriate here on SO:
https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues/103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure those values appear in your data.  Here's an example:

```
var xValues = ["M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa", "Su"];
    svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400),
    data = [
      { "cat": "W", "val": 123456789 },
      { "cat": "F", "val": 234567890 }
    ],
    c = new dimple.chart(svg, data),
    x = c.addCategoryAxis("x", "cat"),
    y = c.addMeasureAxis("y", "val"),
    s = c.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);

// Append a row with no value for each x category you want
xValues.forEach(function (d) {
    data.push({"cat": d})
}, this);

// Set the ordering as you did before
x.addOrderRule(xValues);

c.draw();
```

http://jsbin.com/hosobo/7/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks!  I'll use this.  I'd think it's a useful feature to add without workaround, as it must be commonplace to know all your categories but be displaying ever-changing subsets of the data (as in my case).  It could be an extension/variant of addOrderRule, maybe.

Comment: Interested in a patch for this?  If so, what interface do you prefer?

Comment: Honestly I'm not really sure it has a place.  The code to do it is pretty simple and I'm not sure where I'd fit it in the API.  The order rule doesn't feel right because it's a behaviour distinct from ordering.